# I have a file with content like [(a,b)(c,d)(a,e)] i want to map a to b & e, c to d. How to keep this as a program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have retrieved some data from database which consists of user name and locations which he will be using for work. some users might use multiple locations. i have keep this data in excel clearly through python.

input :
`[(a,b)(c,d)(e,f)(a,g)]` content is in file

output:

```
a:b,g c:d e:f
```

Comment: Why isn't a:b,g this a:b:g

Answer (score 0):

1 possible solution is to create a dictionary and then append 2nd values of tuple to the key. I took the liberty of transforming elements to string to make minimal working code snippet.

```
lst = [('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f'), ('a','g')]
d = {}
for k,v in lst:
    d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': ['b', 'g'], 'c': ['d'], 'e': ['f']}
```

Comment: Actually like this format so much content is there in .txt file. I tried to put the same logic in it.i got error like ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Then you'll need to provide some context as to what these values represent. Could you provide a snippet of this txt file?